# Input/output error when installing mysql with homebrew

Tags: mysql, io, homebrew

he progress so far is as follows.

1. `brew install mysql`
2. 

```
brew services restart mysql
==> Successfully stopped `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
==> Successfully started `mysql` (label: homebrew.mxcl.mysql)
```

3. 

```
mysql.server start
Starting MySQL
./opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1/bin/mysqld_safe: line 199: 19245 Abort trap: 6           env MYSQLD_PARENT_PID=19134 nohup /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1/bin/mysqld --basedir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1 --datadir=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql --plugin-dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql/8.2.0_1/lib/plugin --log-error=jeong-yeonghyeon-ui-MacBookAir.local.err --pid-file=/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/jeong-yeonghyeon-ui-MacBookAir.local.pid < /dev/null >> /opt/homebrew/var/mysql/jeong-yeonghyeon-ui-MacBookAir.local.err 2>&1
 ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/opt/homebrew/var/mysql/jeong-yeonghyeon-ui-MacBookAir.local.pid).
```

I wonder why the 'mysql.server start' sentence and the error log come up. Is it an input/output problem? I think there is an input/output problem before the problem that mysql doesn't start...

So far, I haven't seen anything like that happen while looking for the problem with mysql.